# Is it possible to check timeout on jQuery.post()?

Tags: ajax, jquery, timeout

I have this code requesting some folder info from a mysql DB:

```
function gotoDir(pmcat_id, pcat_id){
    $('#slideshowContainer').html('<img class="loader" src="/javascript/ajax-loader.gif">');
    $.post("/publish/includes/content.includes/functions.slideshow.php", 
        {  updateSlideshowDir: 1, pmcat_id: pmcat_id, pcat_id: pcat_id },
        function(data){
             $('#pageSlideshow').html(data.content);
        }, "json"
    );
}
```

Sometimes the post request times out because of bad internet connection. Is it possible to set a timeout check on $.post() ? Ex: if $.post() uses more then X ms, reload the request.

UPDATE: Looks like I found a solution:

```
function gotoDir(pmcat_id, pcat_id){
    $('#slideshowContainer').html('<img class="loader" src="/javascript/ajax-loader.gif">');
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"/publish/includes/content.includes/functions.slideshow.php",
        data: { updateSlideshowDir: 1, pmcat_id: pmcat_id, pcat_id: pcat_id },
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
            if (data == null){
            alert('ajax failed. reloading...');
            gotoDir(pmcat_id, pcat_id);
        } else {
            $('#pageSlideshow').html(data.content);
        }
        }        
    });
}
```

Is this a OK way to do this? :S

Comment: No it's not Okay, since if the data var equals null doesn't mean the request has timed out, which would cause in an infinite requests if functions.slideshow.php is actually returning null!

Answer (score 29):

$.ajax has all the functions you need to accomplish what you are asking for:

```
function gotoDir(pmcat_id, pcat_id) {
    $('#slideshowContainer').html('<img class="loader" src="/javascript/ajax-loader.gif">');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/publish/includes/content.includes/functions.slideshow.php",
        data: { updateSlideshowDir: 1, pmcat_id: pmcat_id, pcat_id: pcat_id },
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 500, // in milliseconds
        success: function(data) {
            // process data here
        },
        error: function(request, status, err) {
            if(status == "timeout") {
                gotoDir(pmcat_id, pcat_id);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Please note that you don't need to set the *timeout* option unless you want to trigger the error method after a specific time *you* want to set.

Comment: Note that this is also a good template for a longpolling client-side script if you put gotoDir() to the success too :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `$.ajax()` and `$.ajaxError()`, then with "ajaxComplete" you can check if your request `timedout`, or `succeded`.

Source: [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)